# Why does softmax loss become 87.3365 in Caffe training?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

I can only figure out that this relates to FLT_MIN.

With single precision floating-point, FLT_MIN=2^(-126), ln(FLT_MIN)=-87.33654475055310898657124730373.

From the definition of caffe::SoftmaxWithLossLayer :

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1SoftmaxWithLossLayer.html ,

if loss=87.3365, this means the output of FC layer (or the layer before sofmax layer) are all FLT_MIN.

Why does this happen?

Comment: somewhere, the weights or activations are going to NaN. Most probably due to high learning rate or some other parameters. Check them.

Comment: You need to share your train_val.prototxt and solver.prototxt files for better analysis.

Comment: look for common causes for Nans during training

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's think that the `Float_MIN_Point = 1.175494350822288e-38` (2 ^ -126).

With the softmax, we're computing the Napierian logarithm of the loss. Then `ln(Float_MIN_Point) = ln(1.175494350822288e-38) = -87.336544750553109` approximately **87.3365** in absolute value..

Which means, the net is not learning anything at all.

Hint: In my case, I was setting a wrong number of outputs inside the `InnerProduct`